# Catch error but continu iterating the list

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java2, okhttp

I have a function in Kotlin which is doing this :

```
 fun getItemByIds(ids: List<Long>): Single<List<Item>> {
    return Flowable.fromIterable(ids)
        .flatMapSingle { getItem(it) }
        .toList()
  }
```

This working well but in case of an error generated by the getItem such as a http error 404, the code is not continuing to iterate.

getItem is returning a `Single<>` but in case of http error, I return `Single.error(it)`.

What I am looking to do is make sure that the list is still build and in case of an error, I am just dismissing the error and build the list with the item who generate the error.

Any idea ?

Comment: You can call `getItem(it),onErrorReturn(defaultValue)` and later filter them to not collect them in final list.

Answer (score 0):

There's an Rx operator to solve your problem:

```
fun getItemByIds(ids: List<Long>): Single<List<Item>> {
        return Flowable.fromIterable(ids)
            .concatMapEagerDelayError({ id -> getItem(id).toFlowable() }, true).toList()
    }
```

What are the advantages?

1. You'll get the error at the end (if any), and you can decide what to do with it depending on what it is. Maybe you don't want to do the same thing if you get a `NullPointerException` for instance instead of an `IOException`.
2. You can go granular with the overloaded version of `concatMapEagerDelayError` specifying things like `maxConcurrency`.
3. You could even map your errors using `onErrorResumeNext` to find out the ids of the items that errored or you could `retry` / `retryWhen` to specify your retry strategy.

Comment: thanks but I would to just remove it in this function to make sure the list is clean